# Sync multiple angular steppers

Tags: angular, user-interface, events, angular-material2

I'm building an input form app. The app has 2 views (desktop or mobile/tablet). If someone starts inputting responses and the view changes, I want the current step opened in that view.

I've been racking my fingers and brain for a few days on this problem, before coming for help.

I have a parent component with 2 presentation components representing the horizontal and vertical views. For each view, I emit the selectedIndex property of MatStepper<> class from the presentation to the parent, which propagates to the other side.

As I try and solve this, spying the console, I log the selectedIndex as I click through each step. Whats baffling is that when I go backwards through the stepper, the selectedIndex number does not go backwards it increases so it makes programming difficult.

On the parent component I created an observable to contain the selectedIndex emitted from the child components, so the functions that listen for the event emitted will have the right number. I've gotten this far. The current implementation will show the sync working navigating from the top menu. (1-2-3-4)

Clicking on the bottom stepper buttons, no errors, sync breaks(3-2-1). Go back up to top menu (1(sync breaks), (2) errors begin. Namely the errors deal with the bottom stepper not being able to set a property that is internal to the MatStepper class.

If I implement the same code for the bottom menu propagating that currently works for the top menu, does not work, but creates a loop of the emitted data.

As I'm writing this, I considered emitting from the parent to the children to control the navigation. I know my logic is wrong in implementation, because the console.log is not firing..

Take a look at the code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-matstepper-move-rqgfwl)

I'd appreciate any guidance to get the 2-way sync working.

Or tell me if I'm expecting to much here and not sync the steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you wrote a lot of code here trying to solve the issue.

I would start with simple parent component:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-demo [(index)]="currentIndex"></app-demo>
<app-demo2 [(index)]="currentIndex"></app-demo2>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentIndex: number = 0;
}
```

Now let's go back to `DemoComponent`.

**demo.component.html**

```
<mat-vertical-stepper [selectedIndex]="index"
  (children)="move($event)" (selectionChange)="move($event.selectedIndex)">
 ...
```

**demo.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DemoComponent {
  @Input() index: number;

  @Output() indexChange = new EventEmitter();

  move(index: number) {
    this.index = index;
    this.indexChange.emit(this.index)
  }
}
```

`Demo2Component` has the same code.

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-matstepper-move-brsuuy?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks.. Just another learning experience.. I knew the binding was needed, but I did not see this simplicity. I will add to my app and mark as answer, when tested.